# Invalid cast error on querying the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am developing a console app in .NET Core to read/write in a database, using the same code (with minor changes) that my previous app (for the web, written in ASP.NET MVC).

However, when I query the database, the program (that is running) throws an invalid cast exception

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'.'.

But these commands run without issues in my web app.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

A  `.csproj` file:

```
… 
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
…
  <ItemGroup>
… 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.0.0" />
… 
  </ItemGroup>
```

My `Main` routine in `Program.cs`, where I configure the app:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
… 
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<fmDataContext>();

            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));

            using (fmDataContext context = new fmDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
…
```

My query to the database, where the error occurs (in my data context class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
… 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DbConnection connection = Database.GetDbConnection();//)
            using (DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            using (DbDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();
                rows_returned = sda.Fill(dt);
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with console applications. .NET Core 3.x (and EF Core 3.x) use a new library, [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/). Replace the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: Adding to the comment by @PanagiotisKanavos, both namespaces have classes with the same name (e.g. `SqlCommand`) to facilitate moving from .NET framework to core but one needs to take care to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in the core world. See [this announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/).

Comment: Did you try doing a clean build?  The compiler may not recognize the change in Net Versions so the intermediate object files are not getting recompiled with the new library version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET Core 3.0, the SQL Server-related binaries and its data types were moved out of the native `System.Data` namespace and into their own dedicated package, this to make the .NET SDK less bloated.

Those developers who still need to use `SQL Server` can opt-in by downloading the necessary NuGet package at [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/).

> Reference:
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` library uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. So you need to use that instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.